# When video stops it goes to black screen, I need it to go to an image or pause image it was last on

Tags: ipad, screen, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have multiple videos on one view, when one video has finished playing, the user taps a button and the next video starts to play. 
The video that has just played goes to a black screen.

I want the video to stop (pause) where it is, so the image is still there.

this is my code;

```
}

-(IBAction)play {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"origami_panel01" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                     initWithContentURL:url];

    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.controlStyle = NO;
    playercontroller.view.frame = CGRectMake(18, 20, 732.5, 360);
    [self.view addSubview:playercontroller.view];
    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];



}

-(IBAction)play_3 {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"origami_panel02" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                     initWithContentURL:url];

    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;


        playercontroller.moviePlayer.controlStyle = NO;
        playercontroller.view.frame = CGRectMake(18, 395, 233, 233);
        [self.view addSubview:playercontroller.view];
        [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
}
```

It continues like this for a total of five videos.

Please can someone tell me how to make the video pause when another video is played. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not have more than one playback active when using `MPMoviePlayerController`. Whereas being paused also counts as active.

You got at least these two options:

1. Use `AVPlayer` as that baby supports multiple active video playbacks concurrently.
2. Stick with `MPMoviePlayerController` but fake that pause-state by taking a snapshot image from the movie (`thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:`). Then use that image and display it instead of the player.